# Acrobat DC - Change application background color? (GUI too bright)

Tags: user-interface, adobe, acrobat, hex-editors

I'm trying to change (through Hex Editors, Resource Hackers, etc.) the background color of [Adobe Acrobat DC](http://www.acrobat.adobe.com/Acrobat_DC%E2%80%8E), the latest version of Adobe Acrobat.

This version makes the background color much lighter. It's too bright. It hurts my eyes to use, and is distracting from the white-background documents I want to use in it as there is not enough contrast between the application and its documents. 
So, I'm trying to change it myself, as there is [no such option](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1812762) in the preferences.

[image]

I cannot find in what file I need to tweak the code to change the color from F0F0F0 -- almost white, still don't know why they did that. I'm thinking of changing it to 565656 which is how it was in Acrobat XI.

When I use the "Window Info" tool from AutoIt v3 on this area of the program, it drops me the hints in the "Output File" below.

I've already put in feedback to Adobe, but meanwhile, where do I go from here to manually tweak the color?

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  SOP Superbinder Notes.pdf - Adobe Acrobat Pro DC
Class:  AcrobatSDIWindow
Position:   -8, -8
Size:   1296, 776
Style:  0x17CF0000
ExStyle:    0x00000100
Handle: 0x0012077C

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  AVL_AVView
Instance:   32
ClassnameNN:    AVL_AVView32
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:AVL_AVView; INSTANCE:32]
ID: 
Text:   AVPageView
Position:   297, 48
Size:   714, 669
ControlClick Coords:    69, 349
Style:  0x56000000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x00370214
    CoClass AcroAVPageView;
    GUID = {E0E2408B-F751-4C49-8543-A11266600EB6};

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   374, 448
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xF0F0F0

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
AVTaskPaneHostView
AVTaskPaneView
Activate
Learn More
Buy Now
Buy now to continue using Acrobat without interruption.
Free Trial - 29 Days Left
AVScrollView
AVTaskPanelAccordionScrollView
AVTableContainerView
AVTaskPaneBarView
AVFlipContainerView
AVTableContainerView
AVTabStripView
AVSplitterView
AVDockableHostView
AVBookmarkView
AVScrollView
AVTreeViewClass
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVTreeNodeSimpleView
AVSplitationPageView
AVSplitterView
AVScrolledPageView
AVScrollView
AVTableContainerView
8.50 x 11.00 in
AVSplitterDragView
AVPageView
AVTopBarView
1


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
AVTableContainerView
AVDockableHostView
AVCornerView
AVRulerView
55.3%
AVRNAFilesScrollContainerView
AVScrollView
AVTableContainerView
```

Comment: This question is **intended for the Acrobat 2015 Release (Classic)** or near Version 2015.006.30456. 
This is unlike **more recent Acrobat DC** versions (e.g. continuous track), where it's in the View menu: **View > Display Theme > Dark Grey**. 

They just left that out for those who bought it early, like me. I bit on the tool search feature. So I'm still seeking an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the top menu:
Edit > Preferences > Accessibility.

Then under:
Documents Colors Options,
Check `Replace Document Colors`,
Check `Custom Color`,
Click on the color squares to change the document page colors.

This is not quite what you are looking for; however, it may lead you in the direction to finding the source code.

- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC - Version 2020.012.20043.

Comment: As usual (when it comes to adobe UI colour) this answer is incorrect, it explains how to change the document's background colour.